# Best-practice way to make two coupled classes interact

Tags: python, class, oop, project-organization

I am having trouble organizing my code in a well-principled object-oriented way.

**In summary**: I would like to have two separate classes each implement their own functionality (e.g. simulating and plotting, respectively) but somehow combine them (in an extensible manner!) to have a single instance implement both of their functionalities.

**Example:** suppose I have a class that generates data

```
class DataSimulator():
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.N = N
        self.result = None

    def simulate(self):
        self.result = range(self.N) #imagine lots of simulation code here
```

I would also like to plot my data. I could simply add a `plot()` method to the `DataSimulator` but

- I think the `DataPlotter` should be its own separate class since its functionality is completely different from that of `DataSimulator`.

---

**A.** One option I came up with was a separate class that stores a `DataSimulator` instance, then plots it as necessary

```
class DataPlotter():
    def __init__(self, data_simulator_instance):
        self.d = data_simulator_instance

    def plot(self):
        plt.plot(self.d.result) #e.g. using matplotlib

dataSim = DataSimulator(5)
dataPlt = DataPlotter(dataSim)    
dataSim.simulate()
dataPlt.plot()
```

However, in order to use this paradigm;

- I need to always be keeping track of two separate tightly coupled objects. This seems like bad practice. I will never have one without the other, so I'd like to combine their functionality into one.

---

**B.** I considered having the `DataPlotter` inherit from `DataSimulator` like this:

```
class DataPlotter(DataSimulator):        
    def plot(self):
        plt.plot(self.result) 

dataPlt = DataPlotter(5)
dataPlt.simulate()
dataPlt.plot()
```

This is nice because I now have only one instance that does everything I need, but this still seems wrong because:

- It's confusing for the `DataPlotter` instance to be performing the simulation routine
- If I write a `DataSimulatorVersion2`, I can't re-use my `DataPlotter`.

---

**C.** Similarly I also considered the `DataSimulator` to inherit from `DataPlotter`

```
class DataPlotter():        
    def plot(self):
        plt.plot(self.result)  

class DataSimulator(DataPlotter):
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.N = N
        self.result = None

    def simulate(self):
        #lots of simulation code here
        self.result = range(self.N)

dataSim = DataSimulator(5)
dataSim.simulate()
dataSim.plot()
```

This solves the first problem above (I think it makes sense for the simulator to plot its data but not for a plotter to simulate data) but now

- I can't reuse `DataSimulator` if I write a `DataPlotterVersion2`
- Using `self.result` in `DataPlotter` without any guarantee that the variable exists also seems like bad practice.

---

**My question:**

1. Is there a best-practice way of solving this problem? (Is what I wrote in the summary at the top actually what I want, or should I go an entirely different route?)
2. Are the issues that I brought up (in the bullet points) actually valid concerns?

Comment: Having done some more research, I found this discussion to be particularly helpful: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/Gw_l5F6mpjY

Answer (score 2):

I think none of these approaches listed are the right answer. The simulator is intended to produce data, the plotter is intended to consume and use it -- the data is another object here. The plotter is not a simulator and the simulator is not a plotter, and neither of them in theory needs the other one to exist, so they do not have an is-a or a has-a relationship. OOP is intended to use objects to represent the actual things you are working with. I would go as far as to suggest adding another Data class, even if it is just a wrapper around an array or something similarly simple, that your Simulator class outputs and your Plotter class takes as input.

With regards to the bullets --
1. yes, for sure
2. if they are this tightly coupled, consider using an object that is a datamanager instead of something named a plotter or a simulator, as ideologically it would be closer to one object that does two things instead of two that do one thing. If you need a v2, you can inherit from it and overwrite one of the methods that does the plotting/simulating.
3,4,5,6. You are right, these are all bad ideas for the reasons you described.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I would have keep it as simple as possible like you mentioned in your first implementation: two separated classes. DataPlotter can plot any kind of data not only DataSimulator since python does not check types you can pass any other objects. The only constraint is that this object needs a 'result' attribute that suits 'plt.plot' function.